# Permission denied (publickey) When Trying to Connect to Server over Internet

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, internet

Running Ubuntu Server 20.04.01

After port forwarding port 22 on my router, I was able to access my server via ssh by connecting to the IP address. The localhost connection to the IPv4 was still working as well. However, after setting up two-factor authentication using the Google Authenticator I can no longer connect using the IP address only the IPv4 works, and it does verify the authentication code.

Every time it says:

```
sudo ssh username@ip.address 
username@ip.address: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have ensured that the key generated on WSL before connecting to the server (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) is also on the server file (/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys) when logged in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try running the command without `sudo`?

Comment: What does this mean "I can no longer connect using the IP address only the IPv4 works" ?

Comment: @BrianTurek that worked, what's the reasoning on that?

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my comment since it solved the problem.

I think the addition of Google Authenticator was an unrelated event to your problem.  Basically, running a command with `sudo` runs it in the context of the root user.  When you run the command `ssh user@server`, it will look under `/home/$USER/.ssh/` for private keys to use.  When you run it with `sudo ssh user@server`, it looks under `/root/.ssh/` for private keys.  I'm guessing your keys are under your user's account rather than root.